# How to schedule MYSQL Event on Specific Datetime?

Tags: mysql

I am facing an issue want to updating the message table column DateTime using the MySQL event scheduler On DateTime '2022-02-23 23:58:00' where status is open and mes_type is SSG. Please help me to correct my code I will be thankful to you.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT my_event
  ON SCHEDULE AT '2022-02-24 23:58:00' 
  DO
  UPDATE MESSAGE
  SET datetime     = '2022-03-01 23:59:00'
    WHERE datetime = '2022-02-23 23:59:00'
   AND STATUS = 'OPEN' and MES_TYPE = 'SSG'
END */$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please publish your error message in full..

Comment: `DATETIME` is a keyword. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-D Rename the column, or at least quote it with backticks. Also you have lost `;` at the end of UPDATE statement, and excess `*` at the end of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have only 1 statement so you don't need to set delimiters and the end statement is unnecessary but you do need to terminate the update

```
CREATE EVENT my_event
  ON SCHEDULE AT '2022-02-24 23:58:00' 
  DO
  UPDATE MESSAGE
  SET datetime     = '2022-03-01 23:59:00'
    WHERE datetime = '2022-02-23 23:59:00'
   AND STATUS = 'OPEN' and MES_TYPE = 'SSG';
```

Comment: thanks its working fine